# React-Beautiful-Dnd - module not resolve on git commit

Tags: reactjs

The build of the existing react project, the Dnd list and drag&drop items are working as expected.

When committing the changes on github repo, I'm getting the following output:

```
Error ---------------------------------------- node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd/src/view/drag-drop-context/index.js:2:45
Cannot resolve module ./drag-drop-context.
2| export { default, resetServerContext } from './drag-drop-context';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error ------------------------------------------------ node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd/src/view/draggable/index.js:2:44
Cannot resolve module ./draggable-api.
2| export { PublicDraggable as default } from './draggable-api';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error --------------------------------- node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd/src/view/droppable/connected-droppable.js:29:23
Cannot resolve module ./droppable.
29| import Droppable from './droppable';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Steps to reproduce

```
1- In an existing project, chekout a new branch, then run `npm install react-beautiful-dnde`
2- Create a new component where you import Dnd package and run some Dnd stuff.
3- The build should work.
4- Commit the changes to your new branch
```

react version on my machine: 17.0.2

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"react": "16.9",
"react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
...
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete your `npm_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run again `npm install`?

Comment: Yep, first thing I tried, didn't worked

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. I snipped the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the file where I was using the package was a JS file, not a JSX...